# Cannot Erase a 64Gb exFat SD Card with Disk Utility | OS Mojave

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, sd-card

I've got a microSD card in an SD adaptor that I accidentally left in during the Bootcamp installation and now it is formatted as exFat rather than Fat-32. I tried erasing it and changing the format, but it says:

[image]

I looked at a couple pages on here and typed in some console commands but they didn't do anything so I'm writing my own question. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks.
Also, here is the info:

[image]

EDIT: I think I found out why it won't erase - there is a windows NTFS format inside the disk, named disk2s1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SD cards frequently have a read-only switch. Perhaps this is on.

[image]

Comment: Image from https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1102/~/sd%2Fsdhc%2Fsdxc-memory-card-is-write-protected-or-locked

Comment: It wasn't that - I think I've found the problem. The SD card has a windows NTFS format inside of it (don't have a clue what that means, but I know it's the problem). I'm searching how to remove that now, but it wouldn't surprise me if I can't find a way.

Comment: Just managed to fix it somehow. Flicked that little switch on and off a couple times and now it works. The windows NTFS thingy is gone and I've got my SD card back. Thanks for the help.